# Как изменять некоторые данные файла json

Tags: python, json

```
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
    f = json.load(f)
    print('Out: ', f)
```

**Out:**  `{'a': {'b': 0, 'c': 2, 'd': 4}, 'e': {'b': 6, 'c': 8, 'd': 10}}`

Если я хочу обновить некоторые данные таким способом, то мне приходится перезаписывать все данные, а мне например нужно изменить значение `'d':10` на `'d':12`

```
with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    f = json.dump({'a': {'b': 0, 'c': 2, 'd': 4}, 'e': {'b': 6, 'c': 8, 'd': 12}}, f)
```

**Вопрос:** Как изменять данные выборочно, не перезаписывая все данные?

Вот как вариант:

```
import json

with open('test.json', 'r') as r:
    r = json.load(r)
    r['e']['d'] = 12
with open('test.json', 'w') as w:
    w = json.dump(r, w)
```

Это по сути тоже самое что и в примере выше, перезаписывает все данные.

Может у кого есть другие мысли

Comment: простыми способами - никак

Comment: json не тот формат, который позволяет комфортно это делать, например если вам надо записать вместо `10` чиcло `101`, да которое еще и находится в начале файла, то это всё равно потребуется перезапись всего файла

Comment: Главное, что тут непонятно - почему вас этот вопрос беспокоит? У вас `json` на несколько гигабайт и вам его нужно часто менять? Тогда вы неправильно храните данные, пересмотрите концепцию. Разбейте один `json` на несколько. Используйте БД, а не файл. Можно ещё что-то придумать. Вы явно решаете не ту проблему, которую стоило бы решать.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну как почему! ссд ведь от записи изнашивается!!!11!!!!111!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файловые системы устроены так, что нельзя перезаписать в файле только несколько символов. Перезаписывается весь кластер на диске, а то и не один. Для NTFS (скорее всего у вас именно эта файловая система) размер кластера по умолчанию (для дисков размером до 32 терабайт) - 4 килобайта. Поэтому, если ваш джейсон меньше 4 кб, то перезаписать данные выборочно невозможно технически.